# How can I reference an existing certificate resource in bicep?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I have an existing certificate that in Key Vault that I would like to reference from my bicep template.

```
resource prodCertificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2020-12-01' existing = {
  name: 'my-custom-certificate-name/123809dsfj2jf09j32123123'
  scope: resourceGroup('certificateResourceGroup')
}
```

The current bicep template will run in a different resource group, `appServiceResourceGroup` and the key vault is under the `certificateResourceGroup`

The above doesn't work because bicep complains that there should not be a slash in the name.

If I just use `my-custom-certificate-name`, I get an error that states

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "ResourceNotFound",
      "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/certificates/my-custom-certificate-name' under resource group 'certificateResourceGroup' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, may I know if you only want to add an existing certificate from keyvault to an existing app or create a new app and simultaneously add the certificate?

Comment: This would be adding a certificate to an existing app service. The plan is to use the thumbprint from the resource

Comment: so are you sure you have an app service cert called `my-custom-certificate-name` in a resource group called `certificateResourceGroup` ? are you targetting the right subscription ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested same scenario which you are trying i.e. import certificate from keyvault in a resource group to an App service present in another resource group.

I used the below code to do it :

```
param name string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param keyvaultid string
param certificatesecretname string
@secure()
param pass string
param exisitingappplanresourceid string
resource prodCertificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2021-02-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: keyvaultid
    keyVaultSecretName: certificatesecretname
    password: pass
    serverFarmId: exisitingappplanresourceid
  }
}
```

**Output:**

**Existing Certificate in Keyvault:**
[image]

**Deployments and parameters:**

[image]
[image]

**Azure portal App service:**

[image]

**Note:** Please make sure to have `Microsoft.Web Resource Provider` to have access to the keyvault. You can do it from portal by going to `Keyvault>>access policies>>add a accesspolicy` and enter `abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd` in service principal search dialog box , so that it will add the the below resource provider to the access policy .

[image]

---

**If you want to add the certificate from keyvault and then create a ssl binding as well then you can use something like below:**

```
@description('Existing App Service Plan resource id that contains the App Service being updated')
param existingServerFarmId string

@description('User friendly certificate resource name')
param certificateName string

@description('Existing Key Vault resource Id with an access policy to allow Microsoft.Web RP to read Key Vault secrets (Checkout README.md for more information)')
param existingKeyVaultId string

@description('Key Vault Secret that contains a PFX certificate')
param existingKeyVaultSecretName string

@description('Existing App name to use for creating SSL binding. This App should have the hostname assigned as a custom domain')
param existingWebAppName string

@description('Custom hostname for creating SSL binding. This hostname should already be assigned to the Web App')
param hostname string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource certificateName_resource 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2019-08-01' = {
  name: certificateName
  location: location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: existingKeyVaultId
    keyVaultSecretName: existingKeyVaultSecretName
    serverFarmId: existingServerFarmId
  }
}

resource existingWebAppName_resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2019-08-01' = {
  name: existingWebAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    name: existingWebAppName
    hostNameSslStates: [
      {
        name: hostname
        sslState: 'SniEnabled'
        thumbprint: certificateName_resource.properties.thumbprint
        toUpdate: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Reference:**

[Microsoft.Web/certificates - Bicep & ARM template reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/certificates?tabs=bicep#quickstart-templates)

Comment: Thanks. My issue was that I didn't create a `resource certificateName_resource 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2019-08-01'`. I tried to just reference one when it wasn't created. I thought by having a certificate in Key Vault, that would be enough and I didn't need to create the resource.